# How to easily Install "make" utility on Sun 5.10 server?

Tags: solaris, installation, sun, make

I have this machine, which doesn't have installed "make" utility, and I need it in order to install other utilities, have you folks done this before on a Solaris 10 machine?

This is the output I got with "uname -a" command:
SunOS qsunx02 5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc i386 i86pc.

There are some information out there, but I couldn't find any useful post.

Answer (score 7):

Actually I just found out that Solaris 10 comes with that tool "installed", but not added on the Path, adding the dir to the path did the trick for me:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sfw/bin
```

Reference: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/no-make-or-gmake-in-solaris-10-full-install-706161/

Hopefully this saves somebody's time.

Comment: +1 for saving me time